# What is an easy way to save a set of arrays to a file and back in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

I've been searching for an easy way with C++ to save a set of variables (in this case, a set of double arrays) to a file, and later load said file and get the set of variables.

Most of the ways that I've read about imply to lump all of the variables into a single array, or (even worse) write a custom class that reads and writes character by character, manually, all of which is impractical since the arrays will have variable length.

Is there a class or library that I could use? (The fact that I am asking this question means that, yes, it's one of the first times I have to deal with files in C++.)

Comment: Not sure what you have access to. But if it is in a windows environment you could access managed code libraries and serialize the object to XML.

Comment: The keywords you're looking for are `serialization` and `deserialization`. You'll find many libraries to do that, with various types of outputs (XML, YAML etc.).

Comment: @Bernesto - I see no reason that you would want to do that when [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) exists. Much simpler, more portable, and better integrated into C++.

Answer (score 1):

The [boost serialization library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) is one option.

Answer (score 1):

The protocol buffers may help:
[protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)